# Usage of correct prepositions when writing Acknowledgement

Tags: prepositions

I am writing an acknowledgement in my dissertation.

I want to tell the following things.

> I thank Dr. AAA for his support and facilitation **in** conducting a field
>   survey. Thank is extended **for** YYY **for the** cooperation that she gave **on**
>   the field measurements.

There are other friends who assisted on my work. Especially Saman Indrajith who did the proof reading this thesis.

As I am a non-native English speaker, I doubt whether I am using the correct prepositions.
So, I look forward to suggestions to understand the correct preposition(s) in this type of special text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to thank Dr. AAA for his support and facilitation in conducting a field survey. Thanks are also extended **to** YYY for her cooperation on the field measurements.

One preposition should be changed. When we "extend thanks," we extend thanks **to** a person.